# Display accepted bounty rate by users having bounty questions

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I found a small problem, which I can better explain on an example. A user [ooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653/ooo) started from time to time bounty for some questions and accept there **after** the week is expire. It is a form of fraud, but one sees only "89% accept rate" by the user. Is it possible to add something like "10% accept bounty rate" by questions with bounty?

I don't want to discomfort to some person. I see the problem as a general problem which can be easy solved with respect of displaying of the text like "10% accept bounty rate".

I personally will no more give *any* answers to [ooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653/ooo)'s questions, but other people will not knows nothing about the problem.

The problem with bounty is a little more hard for persons who give an answer to the question **before** the bounty was started. Updating of the questions and a lot of votes to the questions change nothing (see my answer [what is the best way to optimize my json on an asp.net-mvc site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999955/what-is-the-best-way-to-optimize-my-json-on-an-asp-net-mvc-site/3001933#3001933) for example). How I understand now the stile of working of the user [ooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653/ooo) in the next days he accept my next (and the last) answer [is there a way to programatically set a filter in jquery jqgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311929/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-set-a-filter-in-jquery-jqgrid/3337327#3337327).

I find more fair if updated answers have the same rights to receive at least 50% of bounty as the answers given after the start of the bounty.

**UPDATED**: I want only added, that I have **no idea why** the user not accept the answers during the 7 days. The fact is that in the last two months [ooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653/ooo) for example started 6 questions with bounty:

[is there a way to programatically set a filter in jquery jqgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311929),
[how can i keep my url when my validation fail in asp.net mvc controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289179),
[Sharepoint web services -- The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608887),
[Is it possible to load content dynamically through ajax (instead of upfront) in simile timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092781),
[can you use jquery lazyload on all images (not just ones out of view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036524),
[what is the best way to optimize my json on an asp.net-mvc site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999955)

The last two questions 3036524 and 2999955 (one from me) are now accepted. Probably after the automatic reminding.

I know that after starting of bounty the user lost the bounty. But the user ask a lot of questions. For some questions where he want have more interesting answers he started bounty (he collect reputation mostly from the questions). Independent on whether he accepted the answer **and when** he accepted the question he receive the same answers which he can somewhere read and try (verify). I don't really know why he do this.

From the other side users who invest his time in answering of the question have an interest to receive the bounty or at least receive "thanks! It work.". If one could seen the "accepted **bounty** rate" it would be exactly (or probably more interesting) so important  for the answer as the standard accept rate.

If somebody ask a question and not accept any answer and don't write any comment to the answer he receive mostly the information which he needs. Exactly so is with the questions with bounty. If somebody start a question with bounty he receive qualitative more better answers as without bounty. He receive the same results *independent whether he accept the question within 7 days or not*. Isn't so?

Comment: I'm completely not following the first paragraph; *what* is that user doing wrong? You can't not award a bounty; if you don't award it yourself half the value goes to the highest-voted answer with 2+ upvotes, and you still lose the full amount from your rep. If they are somehow doing something that "cheats" the system the system should be changed to prevent it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user offers a bounty, they are sacrificing their own reputation. If they do not award the bounty, it is still lost. Bounties are no longer linked to accepting answers either, so regardless of when he 'accepts' your answer, it does not mean you will be awarded the bounty unless he *wants* to award it to you.

One thing to note: Bounties are up to the user who offers them. It doesn't matter if your answer is "good enough", in your own opinion, the offerer gets to award it to whomever he pleases (until the bounty expires). Changing this would be unfair to the person who is sacrificing their own reputation to try and get an answer.

As for your questions about changing it so that answers created before the bounty was offered are still eligible to be auto-accepted. This is completely the opposite of the purpose of a bounty. Bounties are for when *none of the answers were good enough*. It doesn't matter if any answerer *feels* that they "solved" the problem, the bounty was offered because they weren't satisfied, so why would it be "fair" for the bounty to be awarded to an answer that they *already* implicitly said didn't solve it?

If a simple "edit" would be good enough to get you back in the running, then users could simply correct some typos or add a link, and then get the bounty awarded to them, despite not helping the OP in any real sense.

Comment: Please read the updated question. I tried to explain my point of view better.

Comment: For better understanding. Reputation or bounty is not very important for me. On the jqGrid forum http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/ you can see me in the top 3 people who posted (I help here without any reputation). Correspond to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=jqgrid&sort=stats I answered the most question asked last time on the subject jqGrid. So I know a little the subject on which was the both question with bounty. But I want to stress one more time, that I see the "accept bounty rate" as a general problem INDEPENDENT on me or ooo user.

Comment: @Oleg, I think you are still slightly missing the purpose of a bounty. Having an 'accepted bounty' rate will encourage people to accept their bounties, but this is **bad**. Bounties exist as a last resort when the system has failed to generate the answer they want. The user then sacrifices their own reputation to try and get what they want, if they *still do not* find a satisfactory answer, we shouldn't be publicizing a low 'bounty acceptance rate' that implies they've done something wrong.

Comment: @Oleg, we DO want users to accept answer (with the checkmark) so that anyone who stumbles on the question in the future will know which answer is *closest* to correct. But a bounty is more specific, a bounty is entirely in the offerer's control.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand your point of view, but you look the the question with bounty mostly from the side of the person who ask the question, and not from the side of the answer. Probably my suggestion is not perfect as a general rule, but to formulate a suggestion which are better for the most cases I have to have access to the current data which I not have currently. Probably having moderation tool (access to which I receive soon) I could find a better suggestion. But till the time I close me question.